# email address in from field on contact form not showing in email header as "from"

Tags: php, forms, field

iv added the header field in the form code but when i receive the email, the "from" field in the email shows a garbled code and not the email address of the person who sent the message. This is my message processing code:

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {   if( $_SESSION['chapcha_code'] == $_POST['chapcha_code'] && !empty($_SESSION['chapcha_code'] ) ) {
$youremail = 'I removed my address for privacy on stack overflow';
$fromsubject = 'A message from your website';
$title = $_POST['title'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$address = $_POST['address']; 
$city = $_POST['city']; 
$zip = $_POST['zip']; 
$country = $_POST['country']; 
$phone = $_POST['phone']; 
$subject = $_POST['subject']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 
$headers = "From: $nome <$mail>\r\n";

    $to = $youremail; 
    $mailsubject = 'Message received from'.$fromsubject.' Contact Page';
    $body = $fromsubject.'

    The person that contacted you is  '.$fname.' '.$lname.'
     Address: '.$address.'
    '.$city.', '.$zip.', '.$country.'
     Phone Number: '.$phone.'
     E-mail: '.$mail.'
     Subject: '.$subject.'

     Message: 
     '.$message.'

    |---------END MESSAGE----------|'; 
echo "Thank you for your feedback. I will contact you shortly if needed.<br/>Go to <a href='/index.php'>Home Page</a>"; 
                                mail($to, $subject, $body);
        unset($_SESSION['chapcha_code']);
   } else {
        echo 'Sorry, you have provided an invalid security code';
   }
 } else { 
echo "You must write a message. </br> Please go to <a href='/contact.php'>Contact Page</a>"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: `mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);` you forgot to add the headers?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it though. Im lost with php so I came here for help. Can you show me how to add this in properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your ^From: header` here:

```
$headers = "From: $nome <$mail>\r\n";
```

But it isn't used when you call `mail()`

```
mail($to, $subject, $body);
```

You need to pass `$headers` as fourth parameter. Else the headers won't take effect

```
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't declared `$nome` anywhere in your code nor `$mail` in:

```
$headers = "From: $nome <$mail>\r\n";
```

And besides that, as [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319381/email-address-in-from-field-on-contact-form-not-showing-in-email-header-as-from/12319426#comment16532318_12319381) mentions, you didn't pass the header into the mail function. See the fourth parameter of the [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).